# UML how to indicate one class sending request to same class

Tags: uml, class-diagram, class-design, system-design, staruml

There are **2 classes** in the scenario under consideration, **User** and **ConnectionRequest**.

The **structures** of the 2 classes are given below:

### **User:**

- **fullName**: *String*
- **username**: *String*
- **email**: *String*
- **password**: *String*
- **bio**: *String*
- **connections**: *Array*
- **timestamp**: *Date*

### **ConnectionRequest:**

- **sender**: *String*
- **receiver**: *String*
- **message**: *String*
- **timestamp**: *Date*

A user can **send a connection request to another user**, or they can **receive a connection request from another user** such as on social media platforms.

What **type of connection/relation** do the 2 classes share?

How can this be **represented using UML notations** in a **class diagram**?

Any **modifications or improvements** to the above model *ignoring other system requirements* are welcome.

Comment: Model the required operations and you will see it more clearly. The stub above is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of sender and receiver from String to User, using two associations.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky. If one user sends/receives a connection request to another user, but you want to use only one association, you’ll have a [**ternary association**](https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/%7Eananda/umlNotes/node161.html), with two ends for the same class `User` (once for the sender role, once for the receiver role) and one for the `ConnectionRequest`.

[image]

Alternative models could use either an association class `ConnectonRequest` of `User` to `User`, or two distinct association between `User` and `ConnectionRequest` each with a different set of roles. at both ends.

Comment: Why would you recommend ternary? In the given scenario, I see one social media connection request that is existentially dependent on one sender and one receiver.

Comment: @JimL. I do not recommend ternary, but I simply answer the question “What type of connection/relation do the 2 classes share?” in which the singular implies one association,  but the requirements imply that one of the parties is at more than one end of the association. Personally I’d prefer two distinct associations, and I would consider association class only if there’s a guarantee that both users are always known throughout the lifecycle of the request.